# Como assim "Empty DataFrame"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Estou aprendendo e fazer uma lição da minha faculdade.
Meu professor pediu usar filtros de tabela de formato `.csv` usando o comando `.query()`
Então original é assim:

```
    Funcionario Escolaridade Genero  Idade  Meses  Salario
1     Fundam.2      M     37      0    16790
2     Superior      M     33     14    15460
3     Fundam.1      F     39     57     4690
4     Superior      F     56     36    18760
5     Fundam.1      F     48      1    10580
6     Fundam.2      F     50     84    18030
7     Fundam.2      F     60     21    15040
8     Fundam.2      F     66     40     6200
10    Fundam.2      F     27     68     4470
11    Fundam.2      F     45     94     2900
12    Fundam.1      M     57     99     6590
13    Fundam.2      M     23      7    15460
14    Fundam.2      F     23     30    11330
15    Superior      M     59     91     6580
16    Fundam.2      O     28     60    18260
17    Fundam.1      F     71     75     4700
18    Fundam.2      F     49     33     3840
19    Fundam.1      M     43     48     2320
20    Fundam.2      M     57     23     7250
```

Eu criei uma aplicação para filtrar com `query.("Idade == 47" or "Meses > 44")`
Então meu professor pediu a deve exibir colunas em ordem assim: "Idade", "Meses", "Funcionario", "Genero".
Eu programei assim:

```
import pandas as pd

dn = pd.read_csv("fake-file14.csv", sep = ",")

x = dn.query("Idade == 47" or "Meses > 44")

df = x[['Idade', 'Meses', 'Funcionario', 'Genero']]

print(df)
```

Isso apareceu:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Idade, Meses, Funcionario, Genero]
Index: []
```

Como assim? Por que aconteceu assim? Já tentei muitas vezes...

OBS: Meu professor quer aparecer assim:

```
Idade  Meses  Funcionario Genero
2      39     57            3      F
5      50     84            6      F
9      27     68           10      F
10     45     94           11      F
11     57     99           12      M
14     59     91           15      M
15     28     60           16      O
16     71     75           17      F
18     43     48           19      M
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Me parece que o problema é a query:

```
x = dn.query("Idade == 47" or "Meses > 44")
```

Isso esta fazendo um `or` entre 2 strings e mandando o resultado para a `query`,
ou seja, se você colocar isso em um `print` esse vai ser o resultado

```
print( "Idade == 47" or "Meses > 44" )
> Idade == 47  # output
```

Como parece não ter nenhum registro com `Idade == 47` o resultado é um `DataFrame` sem registros.

Como deveria ser:

```
x = dn.query("Idade == 47 or Meses > 44")
```

Veja funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/ZS4I8K), e no [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/DismalPoliticalBuckets).

---

Uma outra forma de fazer essa busca:

```
x = dn[  (dn['Idade'] == 47)   |   (dn['Meses'] > 44)   ]  
#               ↑              ↑          ↑
#         tabela verdade 1     |    tabela verdade 2
#                              |
#                   'OR' operador bitwise
```

> Referencia: [pandas.DataFrame.query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)