# Como selecionar apenas linhas alternadas num dataframe?

Tags: pandas

Após refinar muito meus dados, eu preciso agora somente pegar as linhas alternadas dele. Exemplo, indice 239, 444, etc. Uma ideia seria renomear esses index como 0,1,2... e pedir para selecionar apenas os ímpares por exemplo. Mas estou com dificuldade em como executar isso, quase não mexo com pandas, e não sei todas funcionalidades. Agradeceria muito a ajuda!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Relacionado: [Como assim “Empty DataFrame”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/475073/3774)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que só precise resetar o index e selecionar apenas os de index ímpar, assim:

Resetando index:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Selecionar apenas os de index ímpar:

```
df[df.index%2 != 0]
```

Comment: Oi, nesse meio tempo, havia resetado o index para ficar com ele começando do zero. Usei o iloc. que os meninos tinham dito, e testei esse seu também, ambos funcionaram perfeitamente! Gente muito obrigada! São coisas simples, mas como não trabalho com dados, às vezes preciso fazer esses refinos e gasto muito tempo pesquisando, mas é assim que aprendemos! Uma coisa: se eu quiser excluir várias colunas ao mesmo tempo, exemplo: del df.['Time','N2'] não funciona. Só funciona se for uma por uma, a sintaxe está errada?

Comment: @user217614 Use o drop