# Como faço para filtrar uma linha do DataFrame conhecendo um valor String de uma das suas colunas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Digamos que eu tenho em mãos este dataframe

E eu saiba que um valor específico dentro de uma coluna chamada "Código", contém uma String que chamarei de "mxrf11", no dataframe inteiro não vai ter outro nome ''mxrf11'' na coluna "código" (Estou comentando isso porque não sei se é relevante ter valores repetidos, mas no caso deste DataFrame nenhum nome da coluna "Códigos" se repete)

Como faço para puxar a linha de informações do DataFrame relacionadas ao codigo "mxrf11"?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

edit 1 : Tentando a solução do primeiro comentário

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Algo estranho aconteceu, ele deu os nomes das colunas do DataFrame ao invés da informação associada a linha

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Curiosamente, o mesmo problema aconteceu na segunda solução sugerida no post.

edit 2 - O problema era que as letras estavam minúsculas então o DataFrame não retornou nada. Ao substituir pela letra maiúscula todos os métodos retornaram a informação esperada. :)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Relacionado: [Como assim “Empty DataFrame”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/475073/3774)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja o exemplo:

### Criando DataFrame exemplo

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"frutas": ["banana", "laranja", "pera", "uva", "banana", "pera"], "codigo": ["um", "dois", "mxrf11", "quatro", "cinco", "seis"]})

>>> df
    frutas  codigo
0   banana      um
1  laranja    dois
2     pera  mxrf11
3      uva  quatro
4   banana   cinco
5     pera    seis
```

### Filtrando pelo codigo

```
>>> df[df["codigo"] == "mxrf11"]

  frutas  codigo
2   pera  mxrf11
```

### Atribuindo resultado a outro DataFrame

```
>>> df_filtrado = df[df["codigo"] == "mxrf11"]

>>> print(df_filtrado)

  frutas  codigo
2   pera  mxrf11
```

### Filtrando por PARTE do código

```
>>> df[df['codigo'].str.contains("mxr")]

  frutas  codigo
2   pera  mxrf11
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Camarada, algo estranho aconteceu, ele retornou o nome das colunas e não a informação contida nelas. Editei a minha pergunta com a solução que você mencionou

Comment: @Kioolz, exatamente abaixo da linha `df.columns = title` use `df[df['codigo'].str.contains("ALMI11")]` . Isso terá que retornar a linha com índice `3`. Funcionou para mim.

Comment: Funcionou, eram as letras minúsculas!

Answer (score 1):

Criando data frame teste

```
import pandas as pd

codigos = ['cod1','mxrf11','cod2','mxrf11','cod3','mxrf11']
valores = ['teste1','teste2','teste3','teste4','teste5','teste6']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Codigos':codigos, 'Valores':valores})
```

---

Utilize o isin

```
busca = ['mxrf11']
df[df['Codigos'].isin(busca)]
```

Saída

```
   Codigos  Valores
1   mxrf11  teste2
3   mxrf11  teste4
5   mxrf11  teste6
```

---

Utilize o loc

```
df[df.loc[:,'Codigos'] == 'mxrf11']
```

Saída

```
   Codigos  Valores
1   mxrf11  teste2
3   mxrf11  teste4
5   mxrf11  teste6
```

Comment: Aconteceu a mesma coisa que no meu primeiro edit do post, vou anexar outra imagem e upar o código no GitHub para ficar melhor de visualizar o que está acontecendo.

Comment: @Kioolz,boa noite!  O que acontece é que a coluna código do seu exemplo tem valores maiúsculos, então você deve fazer a pesquisa com o correspondente maiúsculo, no caso: MXRF11. Dessa forma serão retornados os valores. Abraço!

Comment: Era exatamente isso, a busca no Python por todos os métodos do post são sensíveis a diferença entre minúsculas e maiúsculas. Testei todos os métodos que vocês mostraram e todos funcionaram perfeitamente, agradeço imensamente pela ajuda :)